# How to differentiate select and add/update query in gremlin?

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server

I have an application which allows user to push Gremlin queries from UI and those queries are executed at a backend gremlin server.

I want to allow only select queries. i.e. any query which will update/modify the existing graph should not be allowed, while all the queries which return something without changing the graph are fine.

Like:

```
g.V().label()          //allowed
g.V(1).properties()    //allowed

g.V(1).property('name', 'new name')   // not allowed
```

How should I identify which query is allowed and which are not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to protect from mutation on the server side is to configure "g" in Gremlin Server with `ReadOnlyStrategy`. An example for this approach can be found in the default Gremlin Server distribution in `conf/gremlin-server-modern-readonly.yaml`. The line of interest is [here](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/3.4.2/gremlin-server/conf/gremlin-server-modern-readonly.yaml#L28) which uses the initialization script of `scripts/generate-modern-readonly.groovy` ([here](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/3.4.2/gremlin-server/scripts/generate-modern-readonly.groovy)) - the main point of it is:

```
def globals = [:]

... 

globals << [g : graph.traversal().withStrategies(ReadOnlyStrategy.instance(), ReferenceElementStrategy.instance())]
```

Comment: I am also using the same traversal at other interfaces where I might have to edit as well. So, can there be any other way, without removing the capability of editing completely?

Comment: could you have two traversal source instances pointed at the same graph - one that allowed mutation and one that did not? maybe that would satisfy your requirement?